# При разбиении DataFrame выводит только первый столбец

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Написал функцию, которая которая разбивает DataFrame на n DataSet:

```
def split_dataframe(dataframe, n_splits = 4):
    num_data = int(dataframe.shape[0]/(n_splits-1))
    data = []
    k_start = 0
    k_last = num_data
    for i in range(1,n_splits+1):
        if i == n_splits:
            k_start = dataframe.shape[0] - num_data * i
            data_ = dataframe.iloc[k_start:]
            data.append(data_)
        else:
            if k_last <=dataframe.shape[0]:
                data_ = dataframe.iloc[k_start:k_last]
                data.append(data_)
                k_start+=num_data
                k_last+=num_data

    return data
```

Когда я разделяю  DataFrame с помощью этой функции, у меня выводит только первый столбец и первое значение столбца берет как название колонки.

Вот пример:

```
d = {'a':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 'b':[8,9,10,11,12,13,14], 'c': [34,54,12,34,56,78,87]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
k = split_dataframe(dataframe, n_splits = 3)

k[1]

         0
12       4
12       5
1245     6
```

Должно быть вот так:

```
    a   b   c
4   5   12  56
5   6   13  78
```

Как сделать правильно?

Comment: У вас какая задача стоит? Написать функцию или разбить датафрейм? Если вам просто нужно разбить датафрейм, почитайте про `pd.cut`, чтобы не изобретать велосипед.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял код в вопросе - вы пытаетесь написать собственную (неэффективную) реализацию функции [numpy.split()](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.split.html).

Решение:

```
n = 3
res = np.split(df, np.arange(n, len(df), n))
```

Результат:

```
In [47]: res[0]
Out[47]:
   a   b   c
0  1   8  34
1  2   9  54
2  3  10  12

In [48]: res[1]
Out[48]:
   a   b   c
3  4  11  34
4  5  12  56
5  6  13  78

In [49]: res[2]
Out[49]:
   a   b   c
6  7  14  87
```